# Simple.Data LIKE Operator in Where

Tags: sql-server, webforms, simple.data

How can we use `LIKE` operator in `WHERE`using `Simple.Data` for `SQL Server` in ASP.Net C#

I need to run this SQL Query

```
SELECT MAX(regid) FROM reg_course WHERE(regid LIKE '%2013%')
```

Finally I achieved this task by aliasing the `max(regid)` column and  querying in this fashion.

`var cid=db.course_test.All()
 .Select(db.course_test.regid.Max().As("maxcourseid"))
.Where(db.course_test.regid.Like(string.Concat("%",DateTime.Now.Year,"%")))
.FirstOrDefault();`

Note

`cid=db.course_test.All()
.Select(db.course_test.regid.Max().As("maxcourseid"))
.Where(db.course_test.regid.Like(string.Concat("%",DateTime.Now.Year,"%")))`

returns the type Simple.Data.SqlQuery

Using `FirstOrDefault` returns Top result. If you don't want you can iterate in collection without using FirstOrDefault

Any other Better way Suggestions??

Comment: interesting. This might help you: http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Retrieve/WhereClauses.html

Comment: Thanks @Lou Sauer Learning from your link I figured out the task.

Comment: don't be hesitant to revert to your original short question and provide your research as your own correct answer. And great that I could help you